# JSF Primefaces datatable match mode for global filter (not individual column)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, filter, datatable

What is the filter match mode for `global filter` (not the individual column filter which defaults to 'startsWith') and how to change it?

The reason I ask is, when I use the global filter with match mode set to 'startsWith' in all my columns, still I get values with 'contains' filter mode. See screenshot below.

[image: country table screenshot]

I shouldn't be getting the rows other than the first row as I specified 'startsWith' in all columns.

Here is my datatable,

```
<h:form id="countryTable">
<p:dataTable rowKey="" value="#{countryBean.countriesList}"
    var="country" selection="#{countryBean.selectedCountries}"
    styleClass="data-table-style" widgetVar="countryTableWVar"
    filteredValue="#{countryBean.filteredCountries}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <div class="align-left">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="countryTableWVar.filter();"
                    style="width:150px" />
            </p:outputPanel>
        </div>

    </f:facet>
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:2%;" />
    <p:column headerText="Numeric Code" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
        filterStyle="display:none" filterBy="numericCode">
        <h:outputText value="#{country.numericCode}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Alpha_2 Code" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
        filterStyle="display:none" filterBy="alpha2">
        <h:outputText value="#{country.alpha2}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Alpha_3 Code" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
        filterStyle="display:none" filterBy="alpha3">
        <h:outputText value="#{country.alpha3}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Name" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
        filterStyle="display:none" filterBy="name">
        <h:outputText value="#{country.name}"></h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

How to change the datatable global filter match mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code of primefaces

[org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.FilterFeature.java](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/feature/FilterFeature.java)

At line 133 you can see primefaces uses `contains` method of `String`

```
if(columnValue.toLowerCase(filterLocale).contains(globalFilter)){
    globalMatch = true;
}
```

So for now there is no way other than changing code according to your needs and building your own primefaces jar.

Answer (score 1):

From Primefaces 4.0 docs:

> Filter located at header is a global one applying on all fields, this is implemented by calling client 
>   side API method called filter(), important part is to specify the id of the input text as globalFilter
>   which is a reserved identifier for datatable.

The use case would be:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}" 
filteredValue="#{carBean.filteredCars}" widgetVar="carsTable">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
            <h:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
    <p:column filterBy="model" headerText="Model" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column filterBy="year" headerText="Year" footerText="startsWith">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column filterBy="manufacturer" headerText="Manufacturer" 
filterOptions="#{carBean.manufacturerOptions}" filterMatchMode="exact">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column filterBy="color" headerText="Color" filterMatchMode="endsWith">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

It doesn't tell anything about `startsWith`or `endsWith` specific cases for global filter. It could be interesting to open a thread on the [issue tracker](http://primefaces.org/issuetracker.html).